# How does the Furyborn bonus interact with a weapon's regular enhancement bonus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons, stacking

I've been looking through the [Magic Weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/) for **Pathfinder**, and came across the [Furyborn](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/furyborn) enchantment. Basically, whenever you damage someone, you get a +1 Enhancement bonus to your weapon against that single target (to a maximum of +5). However, a magic weapon *already* has an enhancement bonus of up to +5, so is this a rare instance of a stack-able bonus, or is this just meant to be a lower-level supplement enchantment until the party can afford better weapons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Furyborn improves the existing bonus.

From the [Furyborn enchantment](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/furyborn) description (*emphasis mine*):

> This special ability can only be placed on melee weapons. A furyborn weapon draws power from the anger and frustration the wielder feels when battling foes that refuse to die. Each time the wielder damages an opponent with the weapon, *its enhancement bonus increases* by +1 when making attacks against that opponent (to a *maximum total* enhancement bonus of +5). This extra enhancement bonus goes away if the opponent dies, the wielder uses the weapon to attack a different creature, or 1 hour passes.

Note the wording here. It's not giving you a *new* enhancement bonus, it is increasing the weapon's *existing* enhancement bonus (all magic weapons **must** have a plain enhancement bonus of at least +1 in order to add special abilities). It can only increase the weapon's enhancement bonus up to +5, the usual cap for enhancement bonuses from magic weapons.

The purpose of this weapon is to essentially grow from the weapon's regular enhancement bonus up to the maximum +5 against more difficult targets (i.e. targets that take more than one hit to defeat). If your magic weapon already has +5 enhancement bonus then the furyborn enchantment is *completely useless*.

Comment: It's definitely useless on a +5 weapon. It's also an awful, redundant choice on a +3 or +4 weapon - since it's a +2 cost enchantment, you might as well just have a weapon which is inherently +5 *all the time* instead - and even on weapons which are only +1 or +2, it seems like you would usually be much better off just having a +3 or +4 weapon for the same price.

Comment: @Carcer Agreed, it's a pretty junk enchantment. I could see it being decent if it only cost +1, but at +2 there's just not a lot of cases where it's worthwhile.

Comment: An argument could be made when you have iterative attacks as it lets you have a +1 or +2 Weapon that is *effectively* +4 or +5 within a round. This could let you spend less on the weapon overall for a minor dip in effectiveness the first time you start in on an enemy. Is it the best? No. But it does help you overcome pesky DR such as Alignments earlier than other options and remain a usable weapon at higher levels

Comment: It's decent for things that spontaneously add enhancement bonuses and qualities to weapons, such as the Fighter AWT Warrior spirit, but other than that it's pretty meh. One could also argue it's decent for TWF as it's cheaper than 2 +5 weapons.

Comment: @Ifusaso I’d quibble with “minor dip in effectiveness,” since you are missing out on the bonuses on precisely the attacks that are most valuable. It’s pretty significant, especially if DR is in play.